# Unable to open SSIS dtproj in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

Visual Studio 2015, latest SQL Server Data Tools (16.5) and Dac Framework (16.5) from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) and SQL Server 2014.

When opening a solution containing the project, the project fails to open with "invalid project" error message in a popup. The details given are:

```
===================================

Invalid project.         (Microsoft Visual Studio)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Project.OpenProject(IProjectStorage storage, String projectPassword, IDTSEvents events)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectLoader.<>c__DisplayClass1.<LoadProject>b__0(String password, IDTSEvents events)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.ProjectProtectionUtils.LoadProjectWithPassword(Boolean askedPasswordOnce, ProjectLoader loader, IWin32Window dialogParent, String& password, ProjectProtectionEvents errorListener)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectLoader.LoadProject(XmlNode manifestNode, String& projectPassword, ProjectProtectionEvents errorListener)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectLoader.DeserializeManifestInProjectMode(XmlNode manifestNode)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectLoader.ConstructProjectHierarchyFrom(ProjectSerialization projectSerialization)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectLoader.Deserialize(TextReader reader)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Project.Serialization.BaseProjectLoader.Load(IFileProjectHierarchy projectHierarchy)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.VsIntegration.Shell.Project.FileProjectHierarchy.Load(String pszFilename, UInt32 grfMode, Int32 iReadOnly)
```

The dtproj file has targeting ProductVersion 13.0.1400.361 (is that right?) and each project configuration (Debug/Release) has TargetServerVersion SQLServer2014

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DeploymentModel>Project</DeploymentModel>
  <ProductVersion>13.0.1400.361</ProductVersion>
  <SchemaVersion>9.0.1.0</SchemaVersion>
  <!-- 
      etc... 
 -->
<Configurations>
    <Configuration>
      <Name>Debug</Name>
      <Options>
        <OutputPath>bin</OutputPath>
        <ConnectionMappings />
        <ConnectionProviderMappings />
        <ConnectionSecurityMappings />
        <DatabaseStorageLocations />
        <TargetServerVersion>SQLServer2014</TargetServerVersion>
        <ParameterConfigurationValues>
```

I'm at a loss how to debug this further - I've upgraded every package and component I can think of. Any ideas what to do next?

Comment: There is no problem with this combination of versions (I use it myself), which probably means that there is a problem with the file. Is this a new project, something you got from another developer? A different version perhaps? A broken file?

Comment: My project's version is `<ProductVersion>14.0.200.51</ProductVersion>`. Was this project created with Visual Studio 2013 perhaps?

Comment: I'll try rolling back the project file a few commits to see if it's maybe a corruption issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error, after some debugging I figured out that it was cause by a bad merge between branches that resulted in **duplicate SSIS:PackageMetaData entries in the .dtproj file**.

Open up the .dtproj file with a text editor and search for all lines containing `<SSIS:PackageMetaData`. Check for duplicates in the `SSIS:Name` property, and cleanup the file accordingly.